# Angular pass data to a separate page

Tags: jquery, json, binding, model, angularjs

I have a list of items displayed from a service, using ng-repeat. All these items have a "full item details" link (item.html). A generic page that will show more information.

What would be the best way to pass data of the item clicked to item.html so that the information showing comes from the item clicked?

**HTML looks like:**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ItemController">
        <div ng-repeat="item in data.details">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
                <p>{{item.description}}</p>
                <a href="#myModal" class="btn" openmodal>Open modal</a>
                <a href="item.html">View full item details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Data', function(){
    var Data = {};  
    Data.details = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Item 1",
            "description": "Post 1 description - Nullam ac tellus sed mi laoreet placerat.",
            "more": "more info"
        },
        {   
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Item 2",
            "description": "Post 2 description - Cociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.",
            "more": "more info"

        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Item 3",
            "description": "Post 3 description - Nullam ac tellus sed mi laoreet placerat.",
            "more": "more info"
        }
    ]
    return Data;
});

// Controller
function ItemController($scope, Data){
    $scope.data = Data;
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I created my routes, HTML page for each route then use ng-view to show the appropriate content.

See my code below:

```
// Routes
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
                templateUrl:"home.html"
        })
        .when('/task', {
                templateUrl:"item.html"
        })
})

// Controller
function ItemController($scope, $location, Item){
    $scope.data = Item;

    $scope.viewDetail = function(item) {
        $scope.currItem= item;
        $location.path('/item');
    }
}
```

Now the index.html looks like that:

```
<div class="container">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Then I created individual files for my routes:

home.html

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ItemController">
        <div ng-repeat="item in item.details">
            <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
            <a ng-click="viewDetail(item)">View full item details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

item.html

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ItemController">
        <h3>{{currItem.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{currItem.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My link (View full item details) in home.html  uses ng-click to pass the "item" object clicked.
Now I'd like to use this item object within item.html 
console.log(item) gives me the correct object.

I tried to use "currItem" within item.html to display the correct data. It doesn't work.

Not sure what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

It really comes down to how you're structuring your web site and how you want the application to flow.  You have a number of options, the first one being the most Angular way to do it.

1. Make use of [the $route service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route) and [ngView](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angView).
2. Keep everything in-line on one page.  You'd need to replace `<a href="item.html">` with something like `<span ng-click="showDetails(item)">` that would show/hide a separate div which contains the contents of item.html that could be bound to `$scope.currentItem`.  `$scope.showDetails` would look like this: `$scope.showDetails = function (item) { $scope.currentItem = item }`, and item.html would be in a container like: `<div ng-show="currentItem != undefined">...</div>` or similar.
3. Make a request to a new page by changing `<a href="item.html">` to `<a href="item.html?itemId={{item.id}}">`.  This would require a number of additional requests to the sever (not only to load item.html, but also to read `location.search` and then load the data (that you already had on the previous request) back into the new page.

**EDIT**

If you're going with `ngView`, you would have to modify `ItemController` to take a `$route` argument, that you would then use to check the item id like so:

```
app.controller('ItemController', function ($scope, $route) {
    // TODO load the item from some service or using ajax, here's the id:
    console.log($route.current.params.id);
});
```

Comment: He could also make use of Local Storage (HTML5). I think if you add this one, you will point out every possible way.

Comment: @Langdon, Thanks for your response. I'd go the Angular way. I have a few more questions. See my edit.

Comment: @Langdon, considering everything between the header and footer needs to be replaced (same for a few other pages). Is it better to use ng-view or ng-template (not sure what's the difference)?

Comment: @Patrice Yes, it sounds like that might help if you don't want the whole page replaced.  The only issue with ngTemplate (again, depending on your implementation) is that it's not as modular as ngView w/ a separate file.

Comment: @Patrice I'm not sure from your description.  Can you set up something on http://plnkr.co that reproduces what you have at this point?  Also, I discovered `ngInclude` which might benefit you here- http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSPdaqR6WrRh9rbP7vUU?p=preview

Comment: @Patrice This is what you're looking for: http://plnkr.co/edit/kBu1rHse8zWu3M4UuIS9?p=preview -- (1) every time your location changes to /item, your controller function gets re-executed, so you lose `$scope.currItem` (2) you needed to pass the item's id in the route and reference it via params (3) all that said, you should absolutely be using 2 separate controllers 1 for the item listing and 1 for the item details.  Good luck!

Comment: @Langdon Great, thanks for the demo. What are the main differences/advantages of using 2 separate controllers?

Comment: @Langdon Trying to clean my code a bit so I created a service (let me know if that's correct) to load my JSON. I tried to re-use the code from your demo to open the "details" page but still facing some issues: http://plnkr.co/edit/aW8XRaV5mAwxxjjRjld2?p=preview

Comment: @Patrice You've got a race condition issue.  `Items.get` is an asynchronous call, so what happens is `$scope.currItem` gets defined before $scope.items is loaded.  You need to move your logic inside your callback. http://plnkr.co/edit/ni38Xsn5jYhmrFXPMksE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what index.html is doing you could pass it as a parameter. e.g.

```
index.html?title={{item.title}}&id={{item.id}}
```

and then use javascript in index.html to get the query string and parse it for display.

Not sure if you have a requirement to implemented this as a different page or could you use different view instead?

If it could be implemented as a separate view there are multiple options there:

- you could use shared service to pass the data to another controller and tie it to the new controller's model. See following link for more details about services. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services
- you could use $scope variable to create a new model for selected item and use an existing controller.